# How to view the weight_decay loss in PyTorch during the training?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I train a model with Adam optimizer in PyTorch and set the `weight_decay` parameter to 1.0.

```
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr, weight_decay=1.0)
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

If I want to compare the number of the `weight_decay` loss and the model loss, how do I view the value of the loss caused by the `weight_decay`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with L2 regularization? If not, you can study it. I find this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/l1-and-l2-regularization-methods-ce25e7fc831c) very helpful.

There is a subtle difference between L2 regularization and weight decay and that is:

> Weight decay is usually defined as a term that’s added directly to the update rule. On the other hand, the L2 regularization term is added to the loss function.

You may find this [tutorial](https://bbabenko.github.io/weight-decay/) helpful to study the differences between weight decay and L2 regularization.

**[Update]** I find the [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g0t3Phly2M&list=PLkDaE6sCZn6Hn0vK8co82zjQtt3T2Nkqc&index=4) by Prof. Andrew Ng very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out it. Do you have any citation for the statement? In Deep Learning (Goodfellow et al.) book, they state on page 227 **the L2 parameter norm penalty commonly known asweight decay.** To my understanding, `weight decay` is a superset of penalizing weights, and it includes L1, L2, and so on techniques, so I am curious what is correct.

Comment: @Hui-PoWang your understanding is indeed correct. I suggest watching this lecture ()https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g0t3Phly2M&list=PLkDaE6sCZn6Hn0vK8co82zjQtt3T2Nkqc&index=4t o have a clear idea on it.